# Como obtener un registro de un nodo, segun el valor de una propiedad, firebase?

Tags: firebase

Actualmente tengo el siguiente nodo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Basicamente lo que quiero es realizar busqueda del registro por el parametro `uid`. Lo que no logro comprender es que me dicen que no lo debo hacer mediante query, entonces cual seria la otra forma?
He intentado con los siguiente:

```
 firebase
              .database()
              .ref('nuevosUsuario')
              .child(user.uid)
              .once('value')
              .then(snapshot => 
                console.log(snapshot.val())
              );
```

pero me imprime en consola `null`.

De antemano muchas gracias, soy nuevo en firebase.

Comment: Prueba de este modo: `firebase
 .database()
 .ref('/nuevosUsuario/')
 .orderByChild('uid')
 .equalTo(user.uid)
 .once('value')
 .then(function(snapshot) {
  var uidValue = snapshot.val().uid;
  console.log(uidValue);
 });`

Comment: Hola pero si se podria realizar mediante query? quieres la solucion mediante query? seria el de @A.Cedano

Comment: Y también me pregunto: ¿ `uid` es único? ¿por qué no lo usas para agrupar todos los otros datos del nodo? Es como si tuvieras dos identificadores en la imagen que muestras.